# Are the characters in BoJack Horseman really anthropomorphic?

Tags: bojack-horseman

I just started watching BoJack Horseman(Season 1 Episode 1) and noticed when a character asked BoJack if he was drunk, he said "I weigh over 1200 pounds." He certainly doesn't look like he weighs that much.

There are several other references to his weight as well such as the restaurant scene where he eats a large amount of bread and then he tries to redirect the blame for his girlfriend leaving him by saying "You think I'm fat."

Is this hint of his weight being "1200 pounds" just a rhetorical device, or is it an indication of him actually being a regular horse? Are there other indications that characters are actually non-morphic in nature?

Comment: How exactly are you defining “anthropomorphic”?  You appear the believe it has a much more technical/precise definition than it actually does

Comment: @stephen I'm aware of the technical definition, but there's an aspect of presentation. [Wolf's Rain](http://images4.fanpop.com/image/answers/1036000/1036759_1287617160779.58res_367_490.jpg) has characters who are presented as humans, but in "reality" they are wolves. I'm not sure if there's a term for this sort of cinematic story telling device where what you see on the screen is not the character's form. I've seen the term "feral" used for animals that look normal but have human emotions, the ability to speak, etc... I'm just not sure if that's the word to use here.

Comment: In-world, the Bojack Horseman “animal” characters are referenced as being whatever animal. Bojack is a horse, not a “horse man” or horse-like”. Princess C is a cat, etc. Yet they are clearly anthropomorphic, as they look and act in a human-like manner

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using "anthropomorphic" with way too much precision. Bojack is an anthropomorphic character because he is a horse that behaves like a human. End of definition.

The factual accuracy of his human/horse features is a different discussion altogether. As you point out, it's not all that consistent. For a comedy cartoon, that's well within the expected range of accuracy: it serves a particular joke in a particular scene.

Answer (score 4):

It's a cartoon, so I think they're just pointing out that he's a horse. They have human like emotions and feelings, so they are anthropomorphic.